# Trying to make this button editable with is-static

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using Vue.js.*

Currently, the other two inputs in my code work but I am trying to change it from an input as shown below to a dropdown.
This is the current way it's coded and it works fine -

```
<input v-bind:class="{'is-static': !foodItem.editing}" type="text" class="input" v-model="foodItem.category">
```

How its coded above lets me edit the text completely which is great in my scenario for the food name and food price but when it comes to the food category I want to change it between the selected fields only and this below is what I have tried. The problem this is giving me is that its editable before even triggering the edit button.

This is what I've tried* -

```
<div v-bind:class="{'is-static': !foodItem.editing}">
   <select v-model="foodItem.category">
      <option>Select Dropdown</option>
      <option>starter</option>
      <option>main</option>
      <option>side</option>
      <option>dessert</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

When using that code above, it seems to allow edits to be made without even pressing the edit but which I have.

This is the button associated with it all -

```
<button class="button is-fullwidth" v-on:click="editItem(index)">{{ foodItem.editing ? 'Save': 'Edit' }}</button>
```

Comment: What is the CSS associated with the `is-static` class?

Comment: Sorry Roy, what is it your asking (*I'm not too experienced).

Comment: It is not clear what controls whether the select is editable. It seems like you expect the `is-static` class on the surrounding div to affect whether the select is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working solution for the drop-down, now is only editable until the edit button is triggered.

```
<td>
 <div class="select is-rounded" v-if="foodItem.editing">
   <select v-model="foodItem.category">
      <option>Select Dropdown</option>
      <option>starter</option>
      <option>main</option>
      <option>side</option>
      <option>dessert</option>
    </select>
   </div>
       <div v-else>
         <input type="text" class="input is-static" v-bind:value="foodItem.category">
       </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the user from editing the `select` field, you should add the `disabled` attribute based on the value of `foodItem.editing`:

```
<select v-model="foodItem.category" :disabled="!foodItem.editing"></select>
```

Here's a minimal working example based on your code ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epmpaxo8/1/)):

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(foodItem, index) in foodItems" :key="index">
        <button @click="editItem(foodItem)">{{ foodItem.editing ? 'Save' : 'Edit' }}</button>
        <select v-model="foodItem.category" :disabled="!foodItem.editing">
            <option>starter</option>
            <option>main</option>
            <!-- more options... -->
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            foodItems: [
                { editing: false, category: 'starter' },
                { editing: false, category: 'main' }
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            editItem(foodItem) {
                foodItem.editing = !foodItem.editing;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```